# Is there any books or tutorial about writing a small database system?

Tags: database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a simple database engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052189/how-to-write-a-simple-database-engine)

Is there any books or tutorial about writing a small database system?
I want to write my own database system for learning.
I want to find a book describing a procedure to implement a database system.
THX!!!

Comment: Why not starting with a simple graphical operating system and then implementing a web browser in it? Fun aside, you could study the SQLite source code to get an impression.

Comment: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/dscb.html